# Como testar se uma instância é dinâmica ou estática?

Tags: php

Digamos que você acesse um objeto que você não sabe como ele foi criado e quer saber se ele foi instanciado como `new \Acme\Foo()` ou se foi apenas retornado `\Acme\Foo`;

Qual o teste mais prático ? (removido o requisito "sem usar Reflection")

Exemplo:

```
<?php

$foo = App::getService('foo');
```

`App::getService()` retornou um objeto que está armazenado em `$foo`;

`$foo` é um objeto dinâmico?

Comment: @gmsantos veja se o exemplo ajudou ?

Comment: Porque não utilizar reflection?

Comment: removido o requisito "sem usar Reflection"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É bem simples! Você pode usar `is_object()`:

```
<?php
class Foo {

    public function hello()
    {
        return 'world';
    }

    public static function hi()
    {
        return 'Joe';
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$bar = Foo;

var_dump($foo instanceof Foo);//true;
var_dump($bar instanceof Foo);//false
var_dump(is_object($foo)); //true
var_dump(is_object($bar)); //false

echo $foo->hello(); //world
echo $bar::hi();//Joe
```

Comment: Ótima resposta e simples. Puxa, como não lembrei deste método!!!

Comment: Nesse seu exemplo, `$bar` contém uma string, por isso dá false.

Comment: Não @bfavaretto. $bar é ``Foo`` em sua forma estática. Veja a melhoria de meu exemplo?

Comment: `$bar = Foo` gera um *notice*, e o valor é interpretado como string (http://ideone.com/F4jN2O). Quando você usa o operador de resolução de escopo `::`, o nome da classe é resolvido dinamicamente, em tempo de execução.

Comment: Mas isto em um contexto de namespaces tem comportamento diferente.

Comment: @gpupo A resolução é sempre dinâmica, que eu saiba PHP não tem o que você chamou de "instâncias estáticas" (eu prefiro chamar de "referências a classes", e deixar o termo "instância" para objetos criados com `new`). A resolução depende do contexto. Por exemplo, `$bar = \Acme\Foo` é um erro de sintaxe, mas `$bar = new \Acme\Foo()` é válido se o namespace e a classe existirem – e nesse caso o nome completo da classe é resolvido em tempo de execução.

Comment: Acabei de confirmar a indicação do @bfavaretto. O PHP não possui referências à classes. Todas as rotinas da API de reflexão que retornam "classes", na verdade retornam Strings com os nomes das mesmas. Exemplos: [`get_called_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php), [`get_parent_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php) e [`get_declared_classes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php).

Comment: Interessante. Mas me pergunto se minha resposta foi invalidada. Ainda acho que ``is_object`` resolve o caso do @gpupo. O que acham?

Comment: @neoprofit Acho que resolve tanto quanto a minha sugestão do `instanceof` (embora não seja necessário usar o nome da classe no seu caso). Meus comentários foram no sentido de esclarecer que não existem referências a classes, como disse o utluiz. Se usar reflection, até é possível pegar algo parecido, mas que seria uma instância de `ReflectionClass` (e portanto [retorna `true` com `is_object`](http://ideone.com/TZTsi3)).

Comment: Aprendi bastante hoje :D

Answer (score 4):

Até onde eu sei, não é possível retornar referência a uma classe em PHP sem usar Reflection. Então, o cenário em que algo retornaria `\Acme\Foo`, e não uma instância, dependeria de Reflection. Seja como for, você pode checar se uma variável contém uma instância de determinada classe com o operador [`instanceof`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php):

```
class Foo {

}
$foo = new Foo();
$fooEhInstancia = $foo instanceof Foo; // true
```

**[Um exemplo ao vivo](http://ideone.com/HG1n2P/)** (repare o *notice* em stderr)

Comment: Não acho que isso responde a pergunta. A mesma refere-se ao caso de instâncias dinâmicas ou estáticas e não a simplesmente saber a origem de um objeto.

Comment: Verdade. Pense que você não sabe que é ``Foo``mas precisa saber se é dinâmica ou estática apenas

Comment: O que vocês querem dizer com instância dinâmica e instância estática, @gpupo?

Comment: @bfavaretto Dinâmica é um objeto instanciado com ``new`` e estático o objeto no escopo global onde podemos acessar propriedades e métodos estáticos sem poliformismo

Comment: @gpupo Não há referências à classes e, PHP. Como já comentei na resposta aceita, os métodos de reflexão retornam sempre uma String com o nome da classe. No entanto, o que é possível fazer é saber se a String representa uma classe válida com o método [`class_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php).

Comment: @utluiz para o teste unitário que tenho em mente, apenas testar se é um objeto instânciado está ótimo. Mas a explicação é muito boa

Answer (score 2):

Veja no exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
  public function func1(){}
  public static function func2(){}
}

$reflection = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');

$func1 = $reflection->getMethod('func1');
$func2 = $reflection->getMethod('func2');

var_dump($func1->isStatic());
var_dump($func2->isStatic());
```

Nele são testados os métodos da classe `MyClass`. Existem, dois, um estático (`func2()`) e outro dinâmico (`func1()`). Esse código foi obtido do desse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299886/php-get-static-methods) do stackoverflow em inglês.

Comment: Não sei o motivo, mas a pergunta pede *"sem usar reflection"*...

Comment: removido o requisito "sem usar Reflection"